# Java ImageIO.read() hanging in a definite iteration structure

Tags: java

I am writing a program that requires me to send images over some sockets. I am writing a function to do this.

```
    public BufferedImage getCardImage(String card)
    {
        waitForProcess = true;
        System.out.println("ask server for card image");
        sendMessage("get card");
        sendMessage(card.replace("//", "_"));
        BufferedImage img = null;
        int count = 0;
        while(count < 5)
        {
            System.out.println("try getting card image");
            try {img = ImageIO.read(new BufferedInputStream(dataInputStream));}
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("error getting image from server: " + ex);
            }
            count++;
        }
        
        
        System.out.println("got card image from server " + img);
        waitForProcess = false;
        return img;
    }
```

for some reason when it enters the loop the image always comes as null on the first iteration and then the thread hangs on the second iteration.

I have tried changing this to a for loop but the same thing happened. I would expect the function to return either a null image or the image from the inputstream and instead it would hang. I have also used an indefinite iteration style

```
    public BufferedImage getCardImage(String card)
    {
        waitForProcess = true;
        System.out.println("ask server for card image");
        sendMessage("get card");
        sendMessage(card.replace("//", "_"));
        BufferedImage img = null;
        while(img == null)
        {
            System.out.println("try getting card image");
            try {img = ImageIO.read(new BufferedInputStream(dataInputStream));}
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("error getting image from server: " + ex);
            }
            count++;
        }
        
        
        System.out.println("got card image from server " + img);
        waitForProcess = false;
        return img;
    }
```

this doesnt hang and has the intended effect, however i dont want the program to keep running indefinitely and would like for it to halt after a maximum number of iterations.

I realize this code snippet may not be sufficient so below is a link to a github repo with all of the code. this snippet belongs to client.java.

WARNING: exposure to the rest of the code may cause irritation and an overwhelming sense of confusion. You have been warned!

https://github.com/mimramon/Draft-Simulator

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you told it to. Which is: Loop, forever, until this operation succeeds. For most kinds of errors, it never will. How to solve it? Stop telling the computer this. Remove the `while` loop.

Comment: And solve the actual problem.

Comment: For a start: what do you think `read` returning `null` means?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @rzwitserloot I understand where you are coming from however the piece of code I submitted doesn't loop forever, and in fact, it shouldn't. Whilst I wrote it in the form of a while loop, it is still a form of definite iteration that iterates 5 times and will typically be compiled into equivalent code to a for loop. Furthermore repeating it actually does fix the issue, as I stated in the post, It will work when using the indefinite loop I just don't want to code in this way as if it didn't work for some reason the program wouldn't halt.

Comment: @tgdavies my understanding is that this occurs when java believes there is no suitable ImageReader for the inputstream, I don't really know how to fix this either, but I would appreciate any possible pointers

Comment: @Miguel 'run 5 times'? What are you talking about? You maintain a `count`. You don't do anything particular when it hits '5'. This code loops __forever__. If you want it to loop at most 5 times, either write `if (++count >= 5) break;`, or make your condition `while (count < 5) { ... }`

Comment: @Miguel this question is now too unfocused; the title is a red herring (it suggests its about an infinite loop, which is explained by your while loop). Once you've figured out the while loop part and you're stuck on the stream part, ask a separate question. And include (somehow) a sample of that data. As written it's not even clear what the data stream _is_ codewise. Even if you include that, without an actual sample of data, nobody can fix this for you.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, so maybe I'm stupid but the condition in the first snippet is while(count < 5 ){ } already? I feel like you misread, perhaps I should remove the second code snippet to avoid confusion? The main question is just why the first snippet hangs.

Comment: I would imagine that the first snippet hangs because you always try to read 5 images from the socket, and you probably don't write that many, so the process is waiting for data. You can verify that by using the debugger or getting a thread dump.

Comment: @tgdavies yes that was it I forgot to add the condition && img!= null. Thanks for the help!